# Error non-numeric value encountered when edit type content

Tags: status-messages

When I edit a type content published I receive the following error:

[image]

THe fields in type content is:

[image]

Maybe a problem in the php version?

Drupal version: 7.75

PHP Version 7.1.24

Comment: Yes, it looks like it might be cause by php version. Please add more details, like PHP version, Drupal version and steps taken in greater detail.

Comment: @MilošKroulík, edited. Thanks.

Comment: I think `parse_size` is used for file size. Have you checked the upload filesize restriction of your image field for valid settings?

Comment: @Hudri, checked it and no problem found. The message not say about file size, but about non-numeric. Thanks